# How do I check which process is consuming a lot of hard disk reading and writing

Tags: disk-usage

Sometimes my laptop is very slow and I found the hard disk light is not blink as normal. Maybe there is a way to check the hard disk speed usage, so I could kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Indicator Multiload:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Comment: Would Indicator Multiload help identify the specific process OP wishes to kill? Or would it just show that disk activity is high?

Comment: I want to know which program or process. This indicator tells me the over-all reading and writing but not individual.

Comment: I apologize, this is not what you were looking for. Wouldn't System Monitor work?

Comment: nope, the system monitor will tell me the memory and cpu usage but no hard disk speed usage.